# oauth 1 not working with httpx and authlib

Tags: python, python-requests, oauth, authlib, httpx

i am currently making oauth 1 signed requests using the `requests-oauthlib` library.

```py
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

self.session = OAuth1Session(
    OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    oauth_token, oauth_token_secret,
    signature_type='auth_header', realm='http://api.twitter.com'
)       
self.session.headers = self.default_headers
self.session.verify = self.verify
self.session.proxies.update(self.proxies)
```

Using this i can successfully make oauth 1 requests. But I need http 2 and would like to use async io. Thats why i am trying to switch to `httpx` and `authlib`.

```py
from authlib.integrations.httpx_client import OAuth1Client

self.session = OAuth1Client(
    OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    oauth_token, oauth_token_secret,
    http2=True,
    headers=self.default_headers,
    proxies=self.proxies,
    verify=self.context
)
self.session.auth.realm = 'http://api.twitter.com'
```

With `requests-oauthlib` i can make signed requests without a problem. But when i try to do the same with `httpx` i get this response:

```json
{
    "errors": [{
        "code": 32,
        "message": "Could not authenticate you."
    }]
}
```

If i take a look with a web debugger i can verify that the authentication header got all the right keys but somehow the request fails while using `httpx`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue or how to debug this properly? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar solution, you should import AsyncOAuth1Client and not OAuth1Client when using httpx.

Comment: [https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth1.html]